# What method of copying a file can handle tildes? (~)

Tags: java, linux, java-7, nio

What java method of copying a file can handle the use of tildes (~), in Linux specifically, without having to manually replace the tilde with `System.getProperty("user.home")` or `"/home/"`?

For example: I want to copy `~/this/path/file.txt` to `~usera/other/path/filea.txt`

I've tried using [`Files.copy(Path a, Path b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), [`FileUtils.copyFile( File a, File b)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)), [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) & [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: `"/home"` is wrong. Root's ~ is usually `/root`, etc.

Comment: If `~/this/path/file.txt` is used then ~ must be replaced with `System.getProperty("user.home")`. If `~usera/other/path/filea.txt` is used then ~ must be replaced with `"/home/"`

Comment: No. `~root/path/to/file` is usually expanded as `/root/path/to/file`. You have to find the home of the `usera` to correctly expand the path.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. Yeah, you'd need to find the home area of the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell handles tilde expansion. No method in Java does that. You can use

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

which will get the current user's home directory (which is `~` in Linux).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I assumed, but I just wanted to be sure.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As long as `Java` is designed to work in all `OS` in bytecode, you cannot have specific `Java` classes as `File` or `Files` with exclusive `linux` dependences.

So, **yes**, you manually must create a method to replace it yourself, but **taking care of checking first host operating system for running app**.